# Open new terminal from script to get user input and use input in script

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, script, shell-script

Is it possible from a background shell script to open a new terminal (xterm, gnome-terminal, whatever), get some user input, close the newly opened terminal and use the data that was input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using something like `zenity` instead.

```
QUEST="$(zenity --entry --title="Answer these questions three" --text="What is your quest?")"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do that using `xterm`:

```
mkfifo answer.fifo
xterm -T window-title-string -n icon-string -e bash -c 'read -p "input-prompt: " answer; echo "$answer" > answer.fifo' &
answer=$(<answer.fifo)
```

See `man xterm` for more information on controlling the size and position of the window and the color and font of the text if you'd like the appearance to be other than the default.

Doing it with `gnome-terminal` would be similar, but with fewer options for initially controlling window size, position and color (you could use `tput` in the `-e` script that you send it, though).

Comment: Thank you too ... another very fine solution. Even a bit more desktop environment independent. I stay with zenity as I always use Gnome/GTK. But good to know.